# Python sum value in Data Frame for each country and keep PopData

Tags: python, dataframe

I am new into Python and stuck within the following task: This is my Data Frame

```
countriesAndTerritories  cases  popData2018
0                 Afghanistan    113   37172386.0
1                 Afghanistan    259   37172386.0
2                 Afghanistan    280   37172386.0
3                 Afghanistan    285   37172386.0
4                 Afghanistan    369   37172386.0
                      ...    ...          ...
17153                Zimbabwe      0   14439018.0
17154                Zimbabwe      0   14439018.0
17155                Zimbabwe      0   14439018.0
17156                Zimbabwe      1   14439018.0
17157                Zimbabwe      1   14439018.0
```

I want to sum the amount of all cases per **country** and add the popdata for each country. I tried it via groupby (first without the popdate) and wanted to connect it with a dictionary which includes the information country:popdata. But it didnt worked, because the aggregated result was a series and I couldnt transform it with df.to_frame().

Do you guys have any ideas about that? My brain is melting already :D

greetz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('countriesAndTerritorie').agg({'cases':'sum', 'popData2018': 'sum'}).to_frame().reset_index()
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Hi, not exactly what I wanted, but luckily I could transform it. with 'popData2018': 'first' it worked well. Thanks!

Comment: 'popData2018' is same for each country that's why 'first' or 'last will work perfectly. Please mention in your question so that other people don't get confused.@xbader